# Using Rsync Transferring files from server to client too much slow?

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, rsync, scp

Actually i am transferring files from one AM5728 Board to another AM5728 board (with Aargo Linux Kernel) with 1Gbps speed.

1. Tested `iperf` command speed is 750Mbps.
2. Transfer files from one board to another board using `SCP` command it speed is 5-6MBPS(48Mbps).
3. Suggested `Rsync` then i installed and transferred files using `rsync` command it speed is 5-6MBPS(48Mbps).

Required file transfer speed is 700Mbps.
Below command used for transfer files:

```
scp Blackmagic_ATEM_Switchers_Windows_8.6.4.zip     root@192.168.31.175:/home/
Blackmagic_ATEM_Switchers_Windows_8.6.4.zip 2% 41MB 4.6MB/s 05:00 ETA
```

...

```
rsync -aP /home/jb4.img.gz 
root@192.168.31.175:~/Desktop
root@192.168.31.175's password:
sending incremental file list
jb4.img.gz                        254,902,272           35%    5.86%MB/s   0:01:16
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned using "**scp**" (i.e. ssh).  No sense repeating good answers provided elsewhere.

Have a look at [rsync](/questions/tagged/rsync) performance **tuning options** provided in **[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/590230/maximizing-rsync-performance-and-throughput-directly-connected-gigabit-servers)** earlier posting.